# Aurora DB : What is the max columns supported in a table? Also, how do I overcome the "ERROR: Row size too large"?

Tags: mysql, amazon-aurora

I'm working on a requirement where I need to store data in Aurora DB. First problem is, it's giving below error at the time of dynamic table creation.

"ERROR: Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 8126. This includes storage overhead, check the manual. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs. [Column limit exceeded]"

Next problem is that the Aurora database is not letting me create a table with more than 200 columns.

I'm using Aurora DB (MySQL 5.7 InnoDB Engine) large instance.

Comment: show the `create table` request that is failing?

Comment: I've never needed a table of more than, say, 30 columns. It's a relational database so you can break it into multiple tables.